# How to run Xcode projects on a physical Vision Pro Device

Tags: visionos, vision-pro

It does not recognize the Vision Pro when plugged into a Mac. Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: Unless you have the Developer Strap the Vision Pro does not connect to the Mac, you need WiFi